# Crystal Reports 2013 14.1 - How to suppress Group Header?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have group header 2a & 2b
2a has empty text box to cause a line break, but I don't want to render this section whenever occurs as first record on each page.  I could able to suppress on first page: supress -> Pagenumber = 1, but then it appears on other pages on top.  Please how to stop this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used a variable.

Inside the suppress function for that group, I have:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared Numbervar isPrintedOnThisPage;
(isPrintedOnThisPage = 0) ;
```

then I have a function named gf2_printedonthispage with this code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared Numbervar isPrintedOnThisPage:=1;
```

and in the group footer for both sections a and b, I have that formula field inserted and it's suppressed, so nothing prints.

also have a formula named ph_printed containing:

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
shared Numbervar isPrintedOnThisPage:=0;       // reset for this page
```

and a copy of that value in the pageHeader section, suppressed so it doesn't show/print.